# Adding and removing a class to a dropdown when dropdown is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

As the title reads, I'm trying to add a class to the dropdown-menu when it's being clicked and is "open", and remove the very same class once the dropdown-menu closes. 
My code adds the class when dropdown-menu is clicked/open, however it won't remove it when dropdown-menu closes.

This is my code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>


    <div class="dropdown" id="dropDownDiv">
       <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdownButton" type="button" 
       id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" 
       onclick="inputEffect()">
          <span class="dropdownText" id="dropText">Vælg mærke</span><i
          class="fas fa-chevron-down fasDropDown"></i>
     </button>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>


    </div>  
</body>
</html>

<script>
function inputEffect() {
    var button = document.getElementById("dropdownMenuButton");
    var element = document.getElementById("dropText");

    if(button.hasAttribute("aria-expanded", "true")) {
    element.classList.add("myEffect");
    }

}
</script>

<style>
.myEffect {
    position: absolute;
    left: 11% !important;
    top: -35% !important;
    background-color: white;
    color: #3faf8f;   
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `hasAttribute()` method has only a single parameter. I am thinking you want to retrieve the attribute value instead. You can use `getAttribute()` for that.

```js
function inputEffect() {
    var button = document.getElementById("dropdownMenuButton");
    var element = document.getElementById("dropText");

    if (button.getAttribute("aria-expanded") === true) {
      element.classList.add("myEffect");
    } else {
      element.classList.remove("myEffect");
    }
}
```

You can also use `classList.toggle(<class>)` to avoid writing the `if` statement altogether, instead of using `classList.add()`.

Comment: This does not seem to work. The class is no longer added when it is clicked.
I've noticed that the div ":     <div class="dropdown" id="dropDownDiv">
gets a class "open" when the dropdown is open. Perhaps the right thing would be to say:
If dropDownDiv has class "open" then add class to it's childrens children (in this case "dropText")

Answer (score 0):

The `hasAttribute` method does not evaluate the value of the attribute, it simply checks whether it exists, meaning your if statement is incorrectly evaluating to true. You want to use `getAttribute`:

```
function inputEffect() {
    var button = document.getElementById("dropdownMenuButton");
    var element = document.getElementById("dropText");

    if(button.getAttribute("aria-expanded") === "true") {
       element.classList.remove("myEffect");
       button.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
    } else {
       element.classList.add("myEffect");
       button.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true");
    }

}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. I've noticed that the div ": <div class="dropdown" id="dropDownDiv"> gets a class "open" when the dropdown is open. Perhaps the right thing would be to say: If dropDownDiv has class "open" then add class to it's childrens children (in this case "dropText")
I don't know if this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way you can solve this problem but this method can have some bugs if not used properly. Also, you will have to ensure that the initial state of the dropdown will be surely closed. You can have it's initial state as open too but you will have to tweak the code accordingly. Just use the method `toggle`.

```
function inputEffect() {
    var element = document.getElementById("dropText");
    element.classList.toggle("myEffect");
}
```

Comment: I've tried this. The issue with this is that I have to click on drop dropdow-menu (the button itself) in order for this to work. So fx. if i click outside the dropdownmenu, which also closes the dropdownmenu, the class will not be removed

Comment: There are several methods in which you solve this problem. First clearify that are you using dropdown from some framework or you have create it yourself. If you have created it yourself then you can use the concept of event bubbling in javascript. Just set an event listener on body element and the state of the dropdown as closed and as soon as an even occurs just trace where it occured. If it occured on the button then toggle the class and set the state of the button to be open.If event happend outside of the dropdown or button then toggle the class again if the state of the dropdown was open

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you not to use the onclick function, but rather a mutation observer so it will toggle when the users clicks in the select, and out. As seen in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okv8fjgd/1/), it triggers not only on click, but also clicking out of the select.And your JS will change to this:

```
        var button = document.getElementById("dropdownMenuButton");
    var element = document.getElementById("dropText");

window.MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver
    || window.WebKitMutationObserver
    || window.MozMutationObserver;

var target = document.getElementById("dropdownMenuButton");

observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutation) {
    if(button.getAttribute("aria-expanded") == 'true') {
    element.classList.add("myEffect");
    }else{
    element.classList.remove("myEffect");
    }
}),
config = {
    attributes: true
};

observer.observe(target, config);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/okv8fjgd/1/

However, if this is not what you want to achieve, simply change your if statement to

```
if(button.getAttribute("aria-expanded") == 'true') {
    element.classList.add("myEffect");
  }else{
    element.classList.remove("myEffect");
  }
```

Comment: This is actually exactly what i want. However, it's not working when i try to implement to my code.
The thing is I've got so much more code in my original code and some things may interrupt the code you wrote.
Is there some other way to trigger the on click when clicking out of the select?
Perhaps without using the "MutationObserver"`?

Comment: Try to change the name of the variables, `element` and `button` variable names might be used in another part of your code. And also remember to delete the `onclick` attribute :) Tell me if that works!

Comment: I've tried copy whole of my HTML and JavaScript into your jsfiddle and that works fine. But when i run it locally i get this error: 

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.